# «ПишИте» или «пишЕте» – как подобрать правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, глаголы, наклонение, времена

Встретился данный отрывок текста, что-то похожее на советы по написанию речи для защиты дипломной работы.

"Описание актуальности работы. Слово «Актуальность работы» выделите жирным. После вступления Вы пишите и обосновываете актуальность исследования. Два три предложения, все зависит от темы и ее подтверждения. Может быть и 4-5 предложений".

Русский язык – мой второй язык, но все мои внутренние инстинкты кричат мне о том, что данное предложение составлено неверно, особенно отрывок "Вы пишите и обосновываете актуальность исследования". На почве этого возникли споры, даже с преподавателем русского языка. Я утверждаю, что в данном контексте должно быть "пишЕте и обосновываете", на что мне отвечают, что это всё в повелительном наклонении и правильно писать "пишИте", но тогда уже получается несогласованность.

Спор уже прошел, но данный вопрос не дает мне жить спокойно: как все-таки должно быть – *пишЕте* или *пишИте*?

Comment: Получается несогласованность — в чём?

Comment: Разница в ударении и наклонении: пИшете - способность писать вообще, но пишИте поручение писать.

Answer (score 4):

Этот текст вообще не очень грамотный (*слов**о** «Актуальность работы», два три*). А Вы правы – такое сочетание глаголов некорректно.
Если использовать повелительное наклонение, как в первом предложении (*что сделайте? – **выделите***), то нужно так:
*После вступления **напишите** и **обоснуйте** актуальность исследования.*
(Без местоимения *Вы*.)
Или так: *После вступления **пишИте** и **обосновываЙте** актуальность исследования*, но тогда не будет согласования с глаголом первого предложения по виду (совершенный/несовершенный).

Если от повелительного отказаться, то только так:
*После вступления Вы **пишЕте** и **обосновываете** актуальность исследования.*